# R: How to check which HTML files were incompletely downloaded

Tags: html, r, file-management

I am on the lookout for a function in R to check if an HTML file was incompletely downloaded, i.e. to read just the last few lines of a given set of files and check if they end with `"</html>"`. What would be the best way to check for this? Related question is how to avoid if one uses `download.file` that an incompletely downloaded file would be left after interrupting a script?

Comment: So, you're presuming that the file is well-formed? If your criteria for "completely downloaded" would mean having `</html>` in the file, just search for that particular string. `any(grepl(...))` might be of help in such case.

Comment: Well I would like the criterion to be to have this at the last 3 lines of the file, and so the question would reduce to how to efficiently read in only the last 3 lines of each file. Any thoughts?

Comment: What OS? The `tail` function in Linux would be very useful here, I would guess. `tail -3 yourfile.txt`

Comment: Ha it would have to be cross platform ideally, that's why I would prefer not to resort to bash linux tools...